# Get ICC ID number of a SIM Card using Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, cellular-network, iccid

Can someone help me to get ICC ID number of a SIM Card using Expo ?
I looked in the expo-cellular library, but didn't found there a way to get it.

I want get ICC ID number of a SIM Card using Expo and show it on my App

Comment: I think this is not possible

Comment: why would you think that @AhmedSbai ? Just curious

Comment: because such a data should be private so I don't think there is a way to access it as a developer